How to import .pyi files in VSCode?
I am trying to use .pyi stub files in VSCode, and I have the following file structure.
.
When I try to import a .pyi in .py script, e.g. in Hellomath.py, I use: import stubshome.Hellomath.
But I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stubshome.Hellomath'.
How can this issue be resolved?

You can create a typings folder in the root directory to hold the .pyi stub files.
Of course, you can also change the following setting too.
    // Path to directory containing custom type stub files.
    "python.analysis.stubPath": "typings",


My file structre is as follows:
pf                                                                                                                                         ├─ .vscode
├─ LICENSE
├─ README.md
├─ VisualOP
│  ├─ Stubs
│  │  └─ _profiler.pyi
│  └─ profiler.py                                                                                                                     And I set  "python.analysis.stubPath": "/pf/VisualOP/Stubs", but I failed to import _profiler.py. My error is ModuleNotFoundError, could you please tell me why? Thank you.

The typings must be in the root directory of the workspace, you can change the typings to another name, but not increase the directory depth. If you are still confused, please picture your complete workspace directory.

I don't think what you're trying to do is possible. Stub files are Python's way of implementing interfaces, they are useful in development environments, that use information contained in them to suggest you proper variable types ets. The Python interpreter itself has no idea of how to handle such files, so it doesn't recognise them as modules.

Thanks for your help! Could you please tell me how to achieve it in pycharm? I tried it PyCharm，but I met the same error which is "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named"

@user24111774 did you go in project settings > project structure, and added your folder as a content root?

Thanks for your help, I cannot tell the problem clearly without images. I have posted a new question , could you please look my profile and help me with it?

@user24111774: usually if you have new information to supply for your question, it is better to edit the existing question, rather than creating a duplicate. (A new question is better if answers have already been given and the new information would change the essence of the question).
